# How to get rid of the version information in API url in tastypie django?

Tags: django, api, rest, tastypie

I am creating REST based APIs for an app using Tastypie with Django. The problem is default API url in Tastypie contains version info in url patterns i.e.

`http://lx:3001/api/v1/vservers/?username=someuser&api_key=someapikey`

I want my url to be free from API version info like this:

`http://lx:3001/api/vservers/?username=someuser&api_key=someapikey`

## urls.py

```
v1_api = Api()
v1_api.api_name = ''
v1_api.register(UserResource())
...
url(r'^api/', include(v1_api.urls)),
```

I am overwriting api_name with an empty string still

`http://lx:3001/api/vservers/?username=someuser&api_key=someapikey` does not work.

How can I get rid of the version info altogether?

Thanks..

Comment: That's not a good idea. You should always version your API. If you change something in the future you'll regret this decision.

Comment: I agree. This is a *feature*. Versioning the API allows you to remain backwards-compatible when you (inevitably) need to add to, or alter the API going forward. Clients that have not updated their calls yet, can still function, while new clients can take advantage of the new APIs features.

Comment: My idea was to direct clients to the latest version of API at any point of them w/o them knowing the version info..

Comment: Very bad idea, their apps will break. Consider the situation when you release new API and their apps start using it without necessary changes.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I am keeping the version info in the url .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Subclass `Api` and override `urls` to remove all the `api_name`-related bits:

```
class MyApi(Api):
    @property
    def urls(self):
        """
        Provides URLconf details for the ``Api`` and all registered
        ``Resources`` beneath it.
        """
        pattern_list = [
            url(r"^%s$" % trailing_slash(), self.wrap_view('top_level'), name="api_top_level"),
        ]

        for name in sorted(self._registry.keys()):
            pattern_list.append((r"^/", include(self._registry[name].urls)))

        urlpatterns = self.override_urls() + patterns('',
            *pattern_list
        )
        return urlpatterns
```

Comment: Thanks dokkaebi for the code snippet. Will be keeping the version info in the REST url for now..

Comment: Probably for the best. Those two little characters could save a world of hurt when you decide to change the API. Out of curiosity, did this snippet work?

Comment: Yeah I've been watching a few talks and there is a big debate about versioning. The argument though is if your API truly is REST not just a JSON HTTP API well then you don't need to version as the response would supply links to other data...

Answer (score 0):

Although tastypie makes supplying `api_name` optional, failing to provide one simply defaults `api_name` to `"v1"`. This behavior can be modified by subclassing `Api` and overriding the `urls` property within `api.py` to behave independently of `api_name`. To achieve the desired URLconf, however, there's still one correction to @dokkaebi's solution worth noting:

```
pattern_list.append((r"^/", include(self._registry[name].urls)))
```

should instead read:

```
pattern_list.append((r'', include(self._registry[name].urls)))
```

in order to avoid the dreaded `//` that would direct your clients to

`http://lx:3001/api//vservers/?username=someuser&api_key=someapikey`
in place of 
`http://lx:3001/api/vservers/?username=someuser&api_key=someapikey`
as intended.

For convenience, I've included the modified code below.

### Solution

```
class MyApi(Api):
"""
An API subclass that circumvents api_name versioning.
"""
@property
def urls(self):
    """
    Provides URLconf details for the ``Api`` and all registered
    ``Resources`` beneath it.
    """
    pattern_list = [
        url(r"^%s$" % trailing_slash(), self.wrap_view('top_level'), name="api_top_level"),
    ]

    for name in sorted(self._registry.keys()):
        pattern_list.append((r'', include(self._registry[name].urls)))

    urlpatterns = self.override_urls() + patterns('',
        *pattern_list
    )
    return urlpatterns
```

### Convention

One of Django’s core philosophies is that URLs should be beautiful; a clean, elegant URL scheme is an important detail in any high-quality Web application. With respect to the validity of this approach, using a custom request header or an accept header will get the versioning job done without convoluting the scheme with the (subjectively) ugly v1/. That is not to say that the URL versioning strategy is without its share of caveats; however, it's quick to implement and predictable in its response.